# Options form with FieldPluginBase?

Tags: views, 8, plugins

I tried some variations on the code below, but I have not been able to pass my custom form options to `render()`.

```
class CustomField extends FieldPluginBase {

  public function query() {
    // This is a custom field.
    // Leave empty to avoid a query on this field.
  }

  protected function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();
    $options['my_options'] = [
      '1' => 1,
      '2' => 2,
      '3' => 3,
    ];
    return $options;
  }

  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    //Form select element.
    $form['my_options'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#title' => $this->t('My Options'),
      '#options' => $this->options['my_options'],
      '#description' => $this->t('Description.'),
      '#default_value' => 1,
    ];
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    return kpr($this->options['my_options']);
  }

}
```

As is the `['my_options']` key is empty. If I create the `$options['my_options']` in `buildOptionsForm()` it does populate the select list in the views field form. Both, however, break the output of the `render(ResultRow $values)` function. No errors, just no output.

How do you create and pass options from `defineOptions()` to `buildOptionsForm()`, and inevitably access them in `render(ResultRow $values)`?

Trying to reference:
[FieldPluginBase::defineOptions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21FieldPluginBase.php/function/FieldPluginBase%3A%3AdefineOptions/8.7.x) and [Field::buildOptionsForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Field.php/function/Field%3A%3AbuildOptionsForm/8.2.x) without success. As well as referencing: https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defineOptions()` method returns the view field options, not the options to use in one of the form elements returned from the `buildOptionsForm()` method.

If you look at an existing `defineOptions()` implementation, for example [`Date::defineOptions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Date.php/function/Date%3A%3AdefineOptions/8.6.x) or [`Custom::defineOptions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Custom.php/function/Custom%3A%3AdefineOptions/8.6.x), you will notice the returned array follows a specific format.

```
protected function defineOptions() {
  $options = parent::defineOptions();
  $options['date_format'] = [
    'default' => 'small',
  ];
  $options['custom_date_format'] = [
    'default' => '',
  ];
  $options['timezone'] = [
    'default' => '',
  ];
  return $options;
}
```

```
protected function defineOptions() {
  $options = parent::defineOptions();

  // Override the alter text option to always alter the text.
  $options['alter']['contains']['alter_text'] = [
    'default' => TRUE,
  ];
  $options['hide_alter_empty'] = [
    'default' => FALSE,
  ];
  return $options;
}
```

The `buildOptionsForm()` method then uses the `$this->options` array to set the default values of the form elements it shows. (See [`Date::buildOptionsForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Date.php/function/Date%3A%3AbuildOptionsForm/8.6.x).)

```
public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $date_formats = [];
  foreach ($this->dateFormatStorage->loadMultiple() as $machine_name => $value) {
    $date_formats[$machine_name] = $this->t('@name format: @date', [
      '@name' => $value
        ->label(),
      '@date' => $this->dateFormatter->format(REQUEST_TIME, $machine_name),
    ]);
  }
  $form['date_format'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this
      ->t('Date format'),
    '#options' => $date_formats + [
      'custom' => $this->t('Custom'),
      'raw time ago' => $this->t('Time ago'),
      'time ago' => $this->t('Time ago (with "ago" appended)'),
      'raw time hence' => $this->t('Time hence'),
      'time hence' => $this->t('Time hence (with "hence" appended)'),
      'raw time span' => $this->t('Time span (future dates have "-" prepended)'),
      'inverse time span' => $this->t('Time span (past dates have "-" prepended)'),
      'time span' => $this->t('Time span (with "ago/hence" appended)'),
    ],
    '#default_value' => isset($this->options['date_format']) ? $this->options['date_format'] : 'small',
  ];
  $form['custom_date_format'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Custom date format'),
    '#description' => $this->t('If "Custom", see <a href="http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php" target="_blank">the PHP docs</a> for date formats. Otherwise, enter the number of different time units to display, which defaults to 2.'),
    '#default_value' => isset($this->options['custom_date_format']) ? $this->options['custom_date_format'] : '',
  ];

  // Setup #states for all possible date_formats on the custom_date_format form element.
  foreach ([
    'custom',
    'raw time ago',
    'time ago',
    'raw time hence',
    'time hence',
    'raw time span',
    'time span',
    'raw time span',
    'inverse time span',
    'time span',
  ] as $custom_date_possible) {
    $form['custom_date_format']['#states']['visible'][] = [
      ':input[name="options[date_format]"]' => [
        'value' => $custom_date_possible,
      ],
    ];
  }
  $form['timezone'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Timezone'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Timezone to be used for date output.'),
    '#options' => [
      '' => $this->t('- Default site/user timezone -'),
    ] + system_time_zones(FALSE, TRUE),
    '#default_value' => $this->options['timezone'],
  ];
  foreach (array_merge([
    'custom',
  ], array_keys($date_formats)) as $timezone_date_formats) {
    $form['timezone']['#states']['visible'][] = [
      ':input[name="options[date_format]"]' => [
        'value' => $timezone_date_formats,
      ],
    ];
  }
  parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

In your case, the array returned from `defineOptions()` doesn't have the expected values (*default* or *contains*) and this is causing the issue you noticed.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->options` and `#options` of the select element are two different things.

See the separator field of [NumericField::buildOptionsForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21NumericField.php/function/NumericField%3A%3AbuildOptionsForm/8.6.x):

```
$form['separator'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Thousands marker'),
  '#options' => [
    '' => $this->t('- None -'),
    ',' => $this->t('Comma'),
    ' ' => $this->t('Space'),
    '.' => $this->t('Decimal'),
    '\'' => $this->t('Apostrophe'),
  ],
  '#default_value' => $this->options['separator'],
  '#description' => $this->t('What single character to use as the thousands separator.'),
  '#size' => 2,
];
```