# Have Value Selected but Label Showing in Views Display Plugin

Tags: views, 8, forms

I am working on a custom Display plugin for Views. In my buildOptionsForm() method, I have the following:

```
$form['inherit_yaxis'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('The title'),
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [
     1 => $this->t('Inherit primary of parent display'),
     0 => $this->t('Create a secondary axis'),
  ],
  '#default_value' => $this->getOption('inherit_yaxis'),
  '#description' => $this->t('The description'),
];
```

In the optionsSummary(), if I do this:

```
$options['inherit_yaxis']['value'] = $this->getOption('inherit_yaxis');
```

It shows 1 or 0 rather than the label that I want ('Inherit primary of parent display' or 'Create a secondary axis').

What should be on the other side of `$options['inherit_yaxis']['value'] =` so that the label shows but the value stays either 0 or 1?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277522/options-form-with-fieldpluginbase

Comment: Thanks for the link, @4k4, but can you spell-out what I should be looking for? I don't see immediate relevance to my question.